# Undefined variable: worklogs_yesterday (View: /home/riwaj/Desktop/projects/dmt-intern-manager/InternManager/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The screenshot of the error is shown below. I get the error mentioned in the title even though I have passed the variable in the home.blade.php.

> Undefined variable: worklogs_yesterday (View: /home/riwaj/Desktop/projects/dmt-intern-manager/InternManager/resources/views/home.blade.php)

[image]

The variable worklogs_yesterday has been passed through its respective controller, despite of that fact it shows the error.

```
    public function index()
    {

        $d = new DateTime('first day of this month'); //first date of current month
        $d = $d->format('Y-m-d'); // changing in Y-m-d format

        $e = new DateTime('last day of this month'); //last date of current month
        $e = $e->format('Y-m-d');  // changing in Y-m-d format

        $today = new DateTime();
        $today = $today->format('Y-m-d');

        $yesterday = new DateTime('yesterday');
        $day = $yesterday->format('D');
        $yesterday = $yesterday->format('Y-m-d');
        $friday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("previous friday"));


        $worklogs = Auth::user()->workLog->take(-7)->reverse();
        $leaves_granted = Leave::where('status', 1)->where('department_id', Auth::user()->department_id)->where('startdate','>', $d)->where('enddate','<', $e)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        $leaves_today = Leave::where('status', 1)->where('department_id', Auth::user()->department_id)->where('startdate','=', $today)->get();

        if($day == 'Sun'||$day == 'Sat'){
        $worklogs_yesterday = Work::where('created_at', 'like', '%' . $friday . '%')->get();
        }else{
        $worklogs_yesterday = Work::where('created_at', 'like', '%' . $yesterday . '%')->get();    
        }




        if(session('role') == 'intern' || session('role') == 'manager'){
            $reset = Auth::user()->isReset;

            if($reset == 0){
                return view('auth.passwords.resetpassword');
            }

        }
        if(session('role') == 'manager'){
            $leaves = Leave::where('status', 0)->where('department_id', Auth::user()->department_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
            $internrole = Role::where('name', 'intern')->first();
            $intern_list = User::where('department_id', session('department_id'))->get();
            $contracts = User::where('isContractOver','1')->where('department_id', session('department_id'))->get();
            $worklogs = Auth::user()->workLog->take(-7)->reverse();

            $interns = array();

            $contractBool=0;

            if(count($contracts)){
                $contractBool = 1;
            }  

            $check = (Input::get('ContractBool'));
            // dd((Session::get('Bool')));

            if(Session::get('Bool')==1){
                Session::put('Bool',$check);
            }

            // dd($contractBool == 1);
            // dd((Input::get('ContractBool')) );

            if(Session::get('Bool') == null && $contractBool == 1){

                    Session::put('Bool','1');
                    // Input::merge(['ContractBool' => '0']);

                    return view('manager.contract', compact('contracts'));    
            }  

            foreach($intern_list as $intern){
                $role = UserRole::where('user_id', $intern->id)->first();
                if($role->role_id === $internrole->id){
                    array_push($interns, $role);
                }
            }

            return view('home', compact('interns','contracts','worklogs','leaves_granted','leaves_today','worklogs_yesterday'));
        }
        return view('home', compact('worklogs','leaves_granted','leaves_today','worklogs_yesterday'));
    }
```

My home.blade.php has:

```
<div class="bn-breaking-news" id="newsTicker1">
    <div class="bn-label">UPDATES</div>
    <div class="bn-news">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: red; font-size: large" id="leaves"><b>Leave Report Today</b></a></li>
            @if($leaves_today->isEmpty())
            <li><a href="#">No One is on leave today</a></li>
            @else
            @foreach($leaves_today as $leave_today)
            <li><a href="#"><b>{{$leave_today->users->name}}:</b> {{$leave_today->reason}}</a></li>
            @endforeach
            @endif
            <li><a href="#" style="color: blue; font-size: large" id="leaves"><b>Previous Work Day's Work Report</b></a>
            </li>
            @foreach ($worklogs_yesterday as $worklog_yesterday)
            @if($worklog_yesterday->users->department_id == Auth::user()->department_id )
            <li><a href="#"><b>{{$worklog_yesterday->users->name}}:</b> {{$worklog_yesterday->work_title}}</a></li>
            @endif
            @endforeach

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bn-controls">
        <button><span class="bn-arrow bn-prev"></span></button>
        <button><span class="bn-action"></span></button>
        <button><span class="bn-arrow bn-next"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: you can try, create the `$worklogs_yesterday`  variable before the initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `$worklogs_yesterday = ' ';` at the top of the code. In case if the two conditions fail it will return null. In your case if the two conditions are fail it won't be return to the view. conditions are `if($day == 'Sun'||$day == 'Sat')` else what ? So here it doesn't return the variable `$worklogs_yesterday`.

```
@isset($worklogs_yesterday)
  //Start foreach loop in view.
@endisset
```

Comment: There is an else part as well where I set ```worklogs_yesterday``` as a different value.

Comment: I know but you also need to initialize it before if conditions. And then check in view if it is not null then do the `foreach` loop.

Comment: or you can simple check another condition in the view and see if it works. Do not initialize it for now and check it. see updated answer.